# How can I use binary search to find Price in jTable?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, binary-search

I want to do a very basic binary search to search for Price, which is at column 4 in my jTable1. Here is the code I have tried to use so far to no avail. There is also a picture below.

```
public class BinSearch {

    public static int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> name, int low, int high, String key) {

        if (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2; //get mid point
            if (name.get(mid).equals(key)) {
                return mid;
            } else if ((key.compareTo(name.get(mid))) < 0) {
                return binarySearch(name, low, mid - 1, key);
            } else {
                return binarySearch(name, mid + 1, high, key);
            }
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        //get contents from columns:
        ArrayList<String> st = new ArrayList<String>();
        int rowCount = jTable1.getRowCount();
        String fPrice;
        int rowIndex = 0; //start from row 0
        int colIndex = 4; //Price is at column 4
        boolean emptyFlag = false;
        do {
            fPrice = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(rowIndex, 1);
            if (fPrice != null && fPrice.length() != 0) {
                st.add(fPrice);
                rowIndex++;
            } else {
                emptyFlag = true;
            }
        } while (rowIndex < rowCount && !emptyFlag);
        Collections.sort(st); //sort the list
        String key = jTextField4.getText(); //get the search keyword
        int low = 0;
        int high = st.size() - 1;
        int searchResult = BinSearch.binarySearch(st, low, high, key);
        print searchResult;
    }
}
```

[image]

The program will run, but entering any values and clicking Search will not do anything. I'm a very basic beginner still learning Java with NetBeans, I don't know if I have even put the code in the right area or if the sorting has worked correctly. Any help to get me unstuck would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The line `print searchResult;` is not valid Java.

Comment: I see, do you know how I could have the results be printed out on completion of the action?

Comment: It should not even compile. To print out the result on the console you can use `System.out.println(searchResult);`, but I do not think that is the cause of your issue.

Comment: With the given code do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong? It seems like trying to perform a basic binary search with one jTable and one search criteria should be simple enough but I can't figure out what I have done wrong at all. I've had some guesses and tried to change the code many times in different ways but nothing seems to work, I think there is probably some fundamental flaw but I can't identify it.

Comment: At a first glance I can't. Since you did not supply a complete example, it is not possible to reproduce the issue oneself and check out what might be wrong. I suggest you either update your example or try debugging it yourself to see where the code does not what you expect it to do.

Comment: I tried to edit the example and add all the code but there's not enough space. Thanks for your effort, I'll keep trying and hopefully can get it to work at some point.

Comment: Why not use a `RowFilter`?

Comment: How does that work? Where should I implement it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the colIndex, but you never use it.

Do you maybe want to use it in this line instead of the 1?

```
fPrice = (String)jTable1.getValueAt(rowIndex, 1);
```

Also you can not expect, that your ArrayList is ordered. I am not sure, if your binary search works, when it is not ordered.

Comment: Ah, yes, I would probably need to define it as 4 rather than 1. I've done that now but it still dones't show any results when I try to perform a search. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: How do you call the binearySearchn function?

Comment: By clicking the jButton1 named "Search" I want to use the ActionPerformed method to call the function and perform the search showing the results. I'm not sure how to call the binary search function if you mean to do it in a different way. Do I need to add more code or a file of some sort? I'm sorry I'm still a beginner with this :S

Comment: Sorry, I failed....
Collections.sort() sorts the String alphanumeric. That means:
30,100,10 will be sorted to 10,100,30 and not to 10,30,100.

Comment: Ahh, so there's a problem with the Collections.sort code! Thanks for this, at least I know roughly where I've gone wrong now. Do you know how to sort it correctly? I don't know if it would be a short snippet of code to add/modify or if I would need to use a different method other than Collections.sort?

Comment: I would suggest you to pre convert the Strings to Integers. That means, that you have to Change your ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Integer> and the String key to an int key. Both shouldn't be a problem. The Collection.Sort should work then.

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for your effort, this one is tough, I know I must have done something wrong but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I tried with a manuel filled Array and it works for me. Can you explain the problems you have? Do you get a exception (which one?) or are you just expecting different results (what are you expecting, what do you get at the moment?)

Comment: I don't get exception, but when I run the program it just doesnt do anything when I enter a price and click Search. I only want to make a basic binary search to query the basic jTable but it seems almost impossible for me to do. All I did to the code was basically add what it shown in the example, but I'm not even sure where I was supposed to add it in the program - under actionPerformed with the jButton or just anywhere in the source code, for example. I don't think the sorting code has worked correctly, or if it does, I don't know how to initialize the actual code. I'd send a msg but can't.

Comment: Ah okay, so meaby your problem is somewhere else. Are you sure that jButtin1ActiomPerformed () is called? Do you use that method somewhere in your code? If you don't now, if it is called add a System.out.println () to the first line of the method and press the button. (Or better debug it, if you know how)

Comment: I just tried to do that but it still didn't work or do anything. Here's a picture of the code as it is now on NetBeans, maybe this will help you get an idea of what I'm seeing: http://imgur.com/a/W3W96

Comment: Oh you have a few errors, try to import the Array List first. Write something in the System.out.println ("testing"). I still don't now, where you call the function.

Comment: Doesn't show anything. One of the errors I think it could be is that I have 2 public classes. One is named FSIS which is the main one I created for the program itself. In the code for jButton1 ActionPerformed it says "Cannot find symbol jTable1 location class BinSearch". The table wasn't created in the BinSearch class, it was created in the FSIS class but I assume I need the public BinSearch class to be written before the jButton1 ActionPerfmed code. So I don't know what to do, or if that is affecting it.

Comment: Can you upload you code on github and send me a link? Would be way easier

Comment: I have an account on GitHub, JadstaSeven. How can I send you the code?

Comment: Just commit the Code to a repository. I will have a look tomorrow!

Comment: I think I've done it, here it is: https://gist.github.com/JadstaSeven/7a0216128979151912cacedc8059eb5f  Thanks, I really appreciate it!